# IIS 6 SMTP how to test email is sending

Tags: windows-server-2003, email, iis-6, smtp

My server(Windows Server 2003) is running IIS 6. It does not seem to be sending any emails. How can I go about trying to find the fault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the fault can be in several places:
Test with telnet to see if you can manually send email from the same machine - if you can't, the issue isn't with the mail server

Comment: I am sending a email to an external account and it is not getting through. The last message I get in telnet is:

Queued mail for delivery

Comment: I see, so it gets queued, but doesn't reach the account. Sounds like it's being trashed or goes into spam. Do you have the sending server set up properly - MX records, RDNS records, no RBL listings?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using [SMTPDiag](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=bc1881c7-925d-4a29-bd42-71e8563c80a9&displaylang=en)

I'd give you a link on how to use it, but new users are only allowed one link.  So Google "using smtpdiag" and choose the first link.

Comment: Guide: http://www.vsysad.com/2012/05/testing-smtp-server-on-server-2008-r2/

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a quick account in outlook express to try and send messages.

Answer (score 0):

when you say not sending any emails, are they being dumped into IIS's badmail folder? are they being removed from the pickup folder?

it sounds like they aren't being picked up from your telnet query

Answer (score 0):

First check that the smtp service is running:-). what code are you using through the IIS server?